# Ionic 2 App fails to load on production build for android version 4.4.2 and below

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic v2 app and am having an issue with an older version of android.

On the versions including or older than 4.4.2, after the splash screen is just a white screen. If I inspect the app, the error is:

```
    Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 't'.
```

('t' in this case is 'AppModule' which was replaced with a t during the  minification step)

When I build my app as a development/debug build, the app can run on my devices running Android 4.4.2. :

```
    $  ionic cordova run android
```

However, if I add --optimizejs or --release then I get the error message i wrote above:

```
    $  ionic cordova run android --release
```

or

```
    $  ionic cordova run android --optimizejs
```

Any ideas to get around this? Should I restrict api level to 21 and above? My guess is there is a browser issue in 4.4.2.

I created a new project from scratch. Added android platform back. Reinstalled plugins.  Still gave me the same results.